# does celeron P600 cpu support SSE2?

Tags: cpu

QDI Advance 9 motherboard is equipped with the P600 Celeron cpu. Does this cpu support SSE2? Lists on WIKI seemes not to be specific about this.

Comment: Precisely which CPU? This one? https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37245/intel-celeron-m-processor-600-mhz-512k-cache-400-mhz-fsb.html

Answer (score 0):

Released in 2010, almost certainly.
Intel Ark - [Intel® Pentium® Processor P6000](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/49058/intel-pentium-processor-p6000-3m-cache-1-86-ghz.html)

SSE2 was first introduced in the Pentium 4 in 2000.
Wikipedia- [SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2)

Comment: Isn't it pretty much mandatory for 64-bit CPUs as well?

Comment: It certainly does support SSE>>>>http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_Dual-Core/Intel-Pentium%20Dual-Core%20Mobile%20P6000%20CP80617004170AF.html